# The quotient space of the equivalence relation $x^2-y = x'^2-y'$

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

On the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ we define an equivalence relation by $(x,y) \sim (x',y')$ iff $x^2 -y = x'^2 - y'$. In other words, I consider the set
$$
\mathbb{R}/{\sim} := \{ [(x,y)] \mid (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2, x^2 - y = c \}.
$$
I need to draw a picture of this quotient set, because I have difficulties of getting a proper intuition how it might look. Then I have to find a subset $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim} \cong V$, as topological spaces.

The first of my problems is to understand better the quotient set. I think I can elaborate the rest, using the universal property for quotients. I kindly appreciate explanations and elaborations on this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might begin by drawing a picture of a few equivalence classes. Or, if you prefer algebra to geometry, check that each equivalence class has exactly one member on the $y$-axis.

Comment: So the equivalence classes are all parabolas, which are opened upwards? Then $V$ should be the entire real line, and the homeomorphism sends numbers on the real line to the respective equivalence class, right? An open subset of the real line will do as well, as it is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right, except that, in the last sentence, "An open set" should be "A connected open set".

Comment: Your characterization of the quotient is not quite right. As it's written, the condition is trivial: $\exists c: x^2 - y = c$ for *any* pair $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. So, you've just defined $\mathbb{R}^2$ again in a strange way.

Comment: Nope, the quotient is $\Bbb R^2/{\sim} = \{\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x^2-y=c\} : c \in \Bbb R\}$.

Comment: That's right, @azif00.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The quotient consists of course of equivalence classes, not of tuples from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it more natural to map the quotient space to the more familiar space to establish a homeomorphism (the is the inverse of what's suggested in the comments). Begin by constructing a map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x, y) = x^2 - y$. Now, verify that the preimage of each point is $c \in \mathbb{R}$ contains the equivalence class
$$
[(0, c)] = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 - y = c \}. 
$$
Thus, $f$ factors through the quotient map $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2/{\sim}$. In other words, $f = \bar{f} \circ p$, where $\bar{f}: \mathbb{R}^2/{\sim} \to \mathbb{R}$ sending $[(x, y)] \mapsto y$ is well-defined.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{R}^2 @>f>> \mathbb{R} \\
@V {p\,} V V @| \\
\mathbb{R}^2/{\sim} @>\smash[t]{\bar{f}}>> \mathbb{R}
\end{CD}
$$
In fact, for each $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $f^{-1}(c) = [(0, c)]$ on the nose, not just containment, so $\bar{f}$ is injective. Surjectivity is pretty straightforward. So, this map is a (continuous) bijection.

You have to convince yourself that its inverse is continuous, as well, but that's not too bad, considering the definition of quotient topology.